# more than one library with package name react native

Tags: android, react-native

Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Comment: Check the gradle file for duplicate declaration of the above said package

Comment: there is no duplication in build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

In android/build.gradle add

```
...
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                ...
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or you can change directly the modules (not recommendable)

.../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is scan all android project and update version of google play services directly to each module build.gradle.

Step 1: Create js file with name android-gradle-fix.js in your project

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs')

try {
  console.log('Fix Start')
  var rootDir = process.cwd()
  // @nhancv: Preparing path
  var androidSettingGradleFile = `${rootDir}/android/settings.gradle`
  var androidSettingGradleFileData = fs.readFileSync(androidSettingGradleFile, 'utf8')
  var pathArr = []
  var keySearch = ".projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../"
  var keyIndex = 0
  while ((keyIndex = androidSettingGradleFileData.indexOf(keySearch, keyIndex)) !== -1) {
    var nextIndex = keyIndex + keySearch.length
    var path = androidSettingGradleFileData.substring(nextIndex, androidSettingGradleFileData.indexOf("')", nextIndex))
    pathArr.push(path)
    keyIndex++
  }

  var newVersion = '11.8.0'
  var key = 'com.google.android.gms'
  // @nhancv: Update version
  for (var i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++) {
    var file = `${rootDir}/${pathArr[i]}/build.gradle`
    var data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    var result = data
    var index = 0
    var logs = []
    while ((index = data.indexOf(key, index)) !== -1) {
      var versionIndexOf = data.indexOf(':', index + key.length + 1) + 1
      var endVersionIndexOf = data.indexOf(data[index-1], versionIndexOf + 1)
      var moduleOrigin = data.substring(index, endVersionIndexOf)
      var moduleNew = data.substring(index, versionIndexOf) + newVersion
      if (moduleOrigin !== moduleNew) {
        logs.push(`Replace: ${moduleOrigin} -> ${moduleNew}`)
        result = result.replace(moduleOrigin, moduleNew)
        fs.writeFileSync(file, result, 'utf8')
      }
      index++
    }
    if (logs.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Fix path: ${pathArr[i]}`)
      for (var j = 0; j < logs.length; j++) {
        console.log(`=> ${logs[j]}`)
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('Fix Done')
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

Step 2: Update npm script in **package.json** file

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./android-gradle-fix.js"
  },
```

When ever you run npm install it will scan all android module and update with specific version 11.8.0 (you can change it in android-gradle-fix.js file)

---

When run npm install it will skip post install and you may facing with error:

postinstall: **cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) node**

==> Fix add — unsafe-perm to npm install like

```
npm install --unsafe-perm
```

Detail here: https://medium.com/p/2fd245027832

Hope it can help you.